# Why is the installation frozen?

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I have an Asus F556U series, 8G of RAM, and trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from USB when I get to the part where it shows the image, the installation freezes.
I've been half an hour now and continue as you see the image.
Is there anything special I need to do to install Ubuntu on Asus?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Try unchecking other options, i.e. just do normal installation. Sometimes due to connection issues this screen seems to be little laggy.

Comment: Once you are done with installation, let me know. I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Impossible. It was frozen in the next step to the "updates and other software". I have started again and freezes again in the step of the image. I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Are you connecting to any network during installation? If yes, please don't connect.

Comment: Hello @Kulfy, why do you say do not connect? It is a trust network ...
So, should I do the installation if I connect to the internet?

Comment: Actually I have doubts on your network. I think it's little bit slow which (I personally think) might be causing issues. Have you unchecked other options that I mentioned in earlier comments?

Comment: Thank you @Kulfy. If I uncheck all the options and disconnect from the network. But it does not work, 18.04 always freezes, each time in a different part. Install 16.01 and I'll try to update to 18.04

Comment: whenever it freezes try to post that here or in a new question. Its always fun to know why it freezes

Comment: Just go for normal installation. That's it.

Comment: Thank you. I already asked in other occasions for that problem and they sent me to questions that did not solve my problem. I have correctly installed 16.01, I will try to update from here.
The installation as you told me worked, but with 16.01, with 18.04 no. It is true that I was able to get more steps of the installation, but it does not complete

Comment: It must be 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to overcome all the problems that my Asus F556U offered me to install Ubuntu 18.04 and it was thanks to @oldfred which showed me the idea of updating the BIOS, and it shows in another question I did: [How to install Ubuntu on ASUS F556U, JournalError error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error)
Seeing other examples and modifying GRUP, changing `quiet spla\sh` by `pci=nomsi` I managed not to freeze the installation and could complete it.
I hope you can help other users