# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a new system with blank hard drive, will I have UEFI issues?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I want to buy a new computer with an ASUS motherboard, and install on it Ubuntu 18.04. The hard drive will be blank with no operating system installed and not even formatted. Will I have any issues with secure boot? The firmware supports UEFI and I guess that the secure boot feature will initially be enabled.

Comment: Hello, first, I would try to install, and if you have problems, you ask a question with all the details. In the community find several questions related to the UEFI. Here is a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#General_principles. It cost me and I solve it by updating the BIOS and I got it with help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error But each case is different

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually when you load optimal BIOS setting, ASUS motherboard will disable secure boot for you if there's no windows there.
2. Ubuntu 18.04 supports secure boot so you will not run into any problems unless you want to use unsigned drivers.

   If you boot installer under efi mode, choosing simple install using entire disk, the installer will create efi partition for you and put relavant efi files into it, so you don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: Thank you. I will update here how did it go when I get my new computer.