# How to solve touch panel problems?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I got to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my ASUS F556UJ laptop with the [help of the community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [follow up queries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error).

After a while using with the mouse, a few days ago the mouse broke and I had to use the "touch panel". I discovered that the "second button" function used to cut and paste among other things, does not work on the touch panel.

I have consulted ASUS , but they tell me that they do not have support for Ubuntu, which I already knew.

I have tried to fix it from: configure >> Devices >> Mouse and touchpad, but there is no way to solve it. Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your laptop’s touchpad doesn’t have ‘physical buttons’ for left and right click, the right click is achieved with two fingers tap.

Don’t worry! You can easily change this behavior and enable right-click on Ubuntu 18.04.

You need to install GNOME Tweaks tool first. It is available in Ubuntu Software Center.

Alternatively, you can install it using the command below:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

In the GNOME Tweaks, go to Keyboard & Mouse in the left sidebar and under Mouse Click Emulation section, select Area.

That’s it. I didn’t need to log out or restart here. You can immediately test it by clicking on the bottom right area and see that the right click is working fine again. If it doesn’t work immediately, you should restart your system.

[LINK TO SOURCE (Abhishek Prakash)](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/)

Comment: @MiguelEspeso you are welcome