# Ubuntu crashes immediately after password entered (windows 10 dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, crash

I have a windows 10 laptop (new), and tried to install Ubuntu 18.04.01 desktop amd64 (iso file), using a USB stick.

I have tried installing the thing 2 times now. **Both times the exact same thing happens**: I install Ubuntu (once in "try ubuntu" mode, the other time immediate install). It says it's successful and asks to restart the pc. I click restart, and *immediately* it freezes permanently, until I force the laptop off. Then whenever I start the laptop and open ubuntu, I have to fill in my password, which I do. **Immediately after pressing enter, the system freezes. no mouse movement and no response to any keys. I can only force the laptop into a shutdown.**

**Things I've tried:**

- Restarting ubuntu many times. The exact same freeze happens every time after I enter my password without exception.
- using boot-repair in ubuntu recovery mode (recovery mode works btw). did not work.
- grub repair in "ubuntu advanced options".

**some facts**:

- I used "unetbootin-windows-661.exe" to generate the USB stick with ubuntu.
- My laptop is [this Asus zenbook pro](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ASUS-ZenBook-i7-7700HQ-Quad-Core-Keyboard/dp/B07JQQZBPB/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1546024789&sr=8-7&keywords=asus%20zenbook%20pro).
- windows does not seem to be damaged by this process, and I can simply start windows normally.

**I hope I have given enough information. Please tell me if I need to give more.**

Comment: Can you please clarify how you are using the USB stick?  You should be able to boot directly from the USB.  This will produce a screen that asks if you wish to try Ubuntu or install it (see https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2018/11/19/beginners-guide-how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-18-10/#7841b2af787d).  Does the computer freeze after you select Try Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI with latest version from Asus? And updated SSD firmware? Most systems need those updates. Some systems have SSD set as RAID even though one drive. Install AHCI drivers into Windows, then change UEFI setting to AHCI. With nVidia you need the nomodeset boot parameter. Issues often common across various models by vendor. May be similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error/1081221#1081221

Comment: You "crashes" are long after the boot process. It's probably the Nvidia issue, needing the "nomodeset" keyword as oldfred suggested. Search this site for Nvidia nomodeset for the fix.

Comment: @CentaurusA, the way I use it is as follows: I boot up the pc, and hold the esc key, so that I can choose between 1. Windows Boot manager, 2. the USB stick. I choose the USB stick, and then I can choose between 1.Try Ubuntu, 2. install ubuntu, 3/4 something else I can't remember. I choose Try Ubuntu. Then on the desktop is an "install Ubuntu" icon. I click that and install ubuntu. This all works, but then it asks me to "restart".

Comment: When I press restart, it immediately freezes. Then when I force shutdown (with shutdownbutton), and restart, I now have Linux as an option in the first boot screen (next to windows boot manager and the USB stick). Then when I choose Linux (the one on my SSD), it freezes again when I fill in my password, as I explained.