# Ubuntu Desktop 18.10 UEFI not booting - cannot install

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, 18.10

Neither live CD nor USB image does boot in UEFI on my system. Black screen, that is all, no grub-efi does show up. So, not even coming close to the point to install or reinstall. With 18.04 UEFI ist fine and works as designed.

Comment: What brand/model system and what video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI from vendor? Black screen usually related to video issues, you may need nomodeset boot parameter. see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: ASUS B150M-C D3 with Intel CPU, UEFI / Bios uptodate, intel graphic chip on board. Have not tried your hint nomodeset as boot parameter. Will do that next.

Comment: Many models of Asus need pci=nomsi. How to install Ubuntu on ASUS F556U, JournalError error?  add pci=nomsi Not sure about your model.  
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error/1081221#1081221

Comment: Well, grub UEFI does not even boot / start ... no way to add a boot flag on boot.

Comment: If UEFI are you pressing Escape key right after UEFI/BIOS screen and before grub starts to load? If UEFI fast boot still on, you may not have time to press any key and need to turn that off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8

Comment: Well, if I am switching off fast boot and boot logo grub does start and I see the grub menu. And I am able to boot UEFI 18.10. No need to set pci=nomsi. So what ist the different between grub UEFI 18.04 and 18.10?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct fix, but it is a way around the installation process.

Install ubuntu 18.04 as you said that it works

Make sure internet connection is working

Go to "Software and Updates" and then "Updates"

For "notify me for new ubuntu version", select, "Any new version"

Open terminal and type "sudo apt-get update"

Open "Software Updater", It will notify that a new verison 18.10 is available.

Download and install and there you go

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, this does end up in an 18.10 System which does not boot after upgrade from 18.04 is done.

Comment: 18.10 takes more than 2 mins on some systems, try waiting for some time while booting up

Comment: UEFI boot crashes already in grub phase, even waiting more than 5 min does change anything.