# Stuck in grub command line during installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

I have Windows 10 on my laptop (ASUS x556u).

When I've decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside with Windows I faced with the next problem: after I set up my bootable USB stick with Ubuntu as primary I see grub command line and cannot start the installation.

Could anybody help, please?

UPD:
One more detail: when I wrote on my USB stick ubuntu ISO image like in official tutorial (tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/…) then I faced with a described problem, but when I use a little bit another Rufus options (Boot selection = ISO image instead of FreeDos) than I could see installation window, but there are errors.

UPD:
[UEFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFPsQ.png)

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? If preinstalled it is UEFI. Besure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI boot mode, but you may need boot parameter(s). How to install Ubuntu on ASUS F556U, JournalError error?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error?noredirect=1#comment1776854_1079540

Comment: @oldfred, I added my UEFI info to the post. Thanks, I'll try to add boot parameters

Comment: That shows system is UEFI, not necessarily Windows install. But if Windows pre-installed by vendor Microsoft requires Windows to be UEFI. Users can install in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. If you have nVidia, you need nomodeset added to linux line in grub menu to boot installer and until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot ubuntu from live cd once again and try to reinstall grub.

You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for this job.

Comment: Actually, I can't run Ubuntu.
One more detail: when I wrote on my USB stick ubuntu ISO image like in official tutorial (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows?_ga=2.80964503.1285581433.1556458939-1014203691.1556344001#0) then I faced with a described problem, but when I use a little bit another Rufus options (Boot selection = ISO image instead of FreeDos) than I could see installation window, but there are errors.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. If you're on uefi maybe you need to enable something like CSM boot in your BIOS, or anything similar, meaning that you can use both UEFI or BIOS bootloader. You can also temporarily disable UEFI and boot your USB without it. If it works - you're ready to install it, but remember that if you have other system like Windows, this method may brick your windows installation. But if you want to install ubuntu only, then it's ok to proceed.