# New install freezes shortly after login

Tags: system-installation, freeze

edit: problem seems fixed after I updated to proprietary graphics drivers.

I recently installed 18.10 and every time I log in, the guy freezes within seconds. The mouse pointer gets stuck first, and then shortly after, the keyboard gets stuck.

I installed from a bootable USB disk, could that be relevant?

How do I move forward?

The laptop is a Asus UX430UN with a Windows 10 install (came preinstalled, I allocated half the disk for the Ubuntu install).

So i7 8550U, 16 GB RAM, Geforce MX150 GPU with 2GB memory.

I thought it'd be a good idea to hit ctrl+alt+f2 at the login screen to install graphics card drivers. I have not been successful with that, but what I have seen, is that the terminal freezes up all the time.

`watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [mandb:2360]`

Comment: Systems spec would be helpful!

Comment: Got it. Updated.

Comment: Hello @ChistoferOhlsson , I had many problems with Asus to install 18.04. Finally I got it by updating the BIOS. (To update the ios, I need to install Windows 10 again) I leave the link to the question I asked and how I got installed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error  You'll already tell if it worked. For installation, search here in the community, how to install in UEFI mode. Luck.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070996/why-is-the-installation-frozen?noredirect=1#comment1757238_1070996

Comment: I flashed the BIOS. Still same problem. Freezes after like 15 seconds. Every time.